# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology induced by the usual distance is not complete.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

My question is not really about proving this fact. Instead, it is about the sense of the sentence. What does "the topology induced by the usual distance" mean? I never understood it clearly.

To prove the proposition, I thought of the Cauchy sequence defined by $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$, which converges to $e$ and does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks!

Comment: A metric induces a topology by defining open balls in the usual way and using them as a basis for the topology.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I have not studied topological spaces yet, but only metric spaces. I only know that the topology of a metric space is a set of its open sets, which satisfy a series of properties (am I right?). So, the sentence "inducing a topology", is just considering the set that I have just written about?

Comment: Topological spaces are collections of open sets and meet certain conditions on there intersections and unions. Basically in any set with any metric you can define a topology if for every point $x$ you create all possible balls $\{ y: |x-y| < r , r \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ these sets will form a basis for a topology just like the balls $(x-r,x+r)$ do in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField OK, so yo mean saying "topology" is equivalent to saying "topological space"?

Comment: Exactly, a topology means we can make it into a topological space. Metrics always allow us to define a topology but there are topological spaces that cannot be turned into a metric space. Topological spaces that allow a metric are said to be metrizable.

Comment: OK! I finally understood it, thanks!

Comment: People here are confused. "Complete" is a property of metric spaces, not of topological spaces. A space is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges. We can define "converge" in an arbitrary topological space, but we cannot define "Cauchy" in an arbitrary topological space.

Comment: For a concrete example, $\Bbb R$ is complete while $(0,1)$ is not, despite the fact that they are topologically the same (they are _homeomorphic_)

Comment: This is an easier problem then you are making it out to be. Take any irrational number like $\pi$. Then consider the sequence consisting of its digits, i.e. $3,3.1,3.14....$. It is easy to see that this is a Cauchy sequence but it can't converge because $\pi$ is irrational.

Answer (score 3):

So first let us start by defining the usual distance on the real numbers.

> **Definition 1:**  The Standard Distance on $\mathbb{R}$, also called the usual distance is defined by $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, \forall b\in \mathbb{R}$
> $$d(a,b)=\vert a-b \vert$$

That same metric can be considered over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now that we have a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ we can create a topology by defining a basis. We start by taking for any point $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ the open interval centered around $a$ to be topologically open i.e. for any positive real number $\epsilon$
$$(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$$

Now we define open sets. We say that a set $A$ is open iff it can be created by taking the union of collection of open intervals. This may be a collection of finite open sets or infinitely many open intervals.

> **Note** We use the term usual metric because this metric reproduces all the normal results we use in calculus suich as open intervals, closed intervals, limits of a sequence, completeness etc.. Which means using the standard metric, you can use what you know about those properties from calculus without reproving them.

Now for completeness

> **Definition 2:** Let $S=\{x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots\}$ be an infinite sequence in a $(\mathbb{Q},d)$. We say that $S$ is complete iff  it has a limit in $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. $$\lim_{i\to +\infty} x_i=x\in \mathbb{Q}$$

Now to prove that $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ is not complete.

Consider the sequence $S=\{3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, \dots\}$ basically the sequence where $x_n$ has the first $n$ decimal places of $\pi$. Clearly
$$\lim_{i\to +\infty} x_i=\pi$$
but $\pi\notin \mathbb{Q}$ which means that technically, $S$ has not limit in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since we found a sequence in $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ that has no limit in $(\mathbb{Q},d)$, we deduce that $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ is not complete.

Hope this helped.

Comment: It was very useful thanks. I liked the example to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a complete metric space.

Comment: "This is certainly true for $(\Bbb R,d)$" What of $x_n=n$?

Comment: my bad :) will fix it. Thank you!

Comment: To prove $\Bbb Q$ is not complete, we need a _Cauchy_ sequence with no limit in $\Bbb Q$. (In fact, we cannot define Cauchy sequences in general topological spaces, which is why it does not make sense to ask if an arbitrary topological space is complete.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Cauchy sequence are well defined in metric spaces. That is why we can talk about completeness in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Sam Yes. The wording of OP's question, however, refers to the topological structure rather than the metric structure, which is nonsense.